# Create a temporay table with more columns than specified in the SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have created a temporary table from another table and it works well. However, I'd like to add a column to the temporary table and then SELECT ALL from the existing table(unoone). Please any insight and thanks upfront

```
 $sql="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unoone_two AS (SELECT * FROM unoone)";
```

enter code here

Comment: Why do you need to make use of a temporary table in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the columns to the `select`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unoone_two AS 
    SELECT u.*, NULL as newcol, CAST(NULL as SIGNED) as newcol2
    FROM unoone u;
```

You can specify a type by using `CAST()`.